# SpringBoot - Application returns 404 Not Found when started in debug mode

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I am experiencing a weird situation where I am not able to get the spring boot application working in Debug mode. The same application responds correctly when started in normal mode. This behaviour is only observed when I am adding [this](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic) external library as dependency in my build.gradle file.

I am very sure the issue is because of the addition of this said library and sure how I should resolve this.

My IDE is IntelliJ

What I have tried so far:

- Clean and rebuild
- IntelliJ invalidate caches and restart

Gradle entry

```
compile "com.mpatric:mp3agic:0.9.1"
```

I can see the application starts correctly from the logs and listening on port 8080. When I make the API call there is no entry in the logs.

**UPDATE**
When I run my application in with debug level logging resolution, I get the following:

```
2019-04-19 23:25:58.267 DEBUG 8212 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1142) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:294) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]

2019-04-19 23:25:58.267 DEBUG 8212 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1f2672ea:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@19ebacea:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57538]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
2019-04-19 23:25:58.269 DEBUG 8212 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch  : Counting down[http-nio-8080-exec-2] latch=2
2019-04-19 23:25:58.269 DEBUG 8212 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@19ebacea:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]] closed
2019-04-19 23:25:58.279 DEBUG 8212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set query string encoding to UTF-8
2019-04-19 23:25:58.283 DEBUG 8212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request POST /v1/agents
2019-04-19 23:25:58.283 DEBUG 8212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2019-04-19 23:25:58.287 DEBUG 8212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.a.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl     : Loading persistent provider registrations from [C:\Users\Vino\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.11733970093983411817.8080\conf\jaspic-providers.xml]
2019-04-19 23:25:58.287 DEBUG 8212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    :  Not subject to any constraint
2019-04-19 23:25:58.303 DEBUG 8212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@2d6dfe49:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@1cc15a:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57539]], Read from buffer: [0]
2019-04-19 23:25:58.303 DEBUG 8212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@2d6dfe49:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@1cc15a:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57539]], Read direct from socket: [0]
2019-04-19 23:25:58.303 DEBUG 8212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@2d6dfe49:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@1cc15a:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57539]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
2019-04-19 23:26:10.967 DEBUG 8212 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2019-04-19 23:26:40.542 DEBUG 8212 --- [Engine[Tomcat]]] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1555680400542 sessioncount 0
2019-04-19 23:26:40.542 DEBUG 8212 --- [Engine[Tomcat]]] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
2019-04-19 23:26:40.969 DEBUG 8212 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2019-04-19 23:26:44.541 DEBUG 8212 --- [nnection-reaper] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
2019-04-19 23:26:44.541 DEBUG 8212 --- [nnection-reaper] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
2019-04-19 23:26:44.541 DEBUG 8212 --- [nnection-reaper] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
2019-04-19 23:26:44.541 DEBUG 8212 --- [nnection-reaper] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
```

So basically the request is reaching the server. The response is getting created but it's not being sent by the server.

Comment: Is it possibel to provide sample project example?